# How to download Ubuntu default sounds in mp3 or wav format?

Tags: sound, themes, windows-10, default, sound-theme

I run Windows 10 along with Ubuntu in dual boot mode but I want to change the windows default sound scheme to Ubuntu sounds. Is there any way to download and save these files in wav format so that I can customize windows 10 sound scheme.

Comment: You can convert it from oga to wav or mp3 using ffmpeg.

Comment: Where  OGAs located??

Comment: You can find them in [Yaru theme sounds](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/y/yaru-theme/yaru-theme-sound_20.04.6_all.deb) package.

Answer (score 1):

If you have Ubuntu installed, you can find them in `/usr/share/sounds/<theme>/stereo` where `<theme>` can be replaced with Ubuntu (if using releases before 18.04) or  Yaru (if using releases after 18.04).

Alternatively, you can download the corresponding packages from [pool of archives](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main) to get [Yaru theme sounds](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/y/yaru-theme/) or [Ubuntu sounds](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/u/ubuntu-sounds/).

Once downloaded extract using

```
dpkg -x deb_name.deb
```

And navigate to `/usr/share/sounds/<theme>/stereo`. To convert the OGG or OGA sound to MP3, you can use [`ffmpeg`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/ffmpeg.1.html). In order to convert all sounds in one go, you can use `for` loop. The below command will convert all OGA/OGG sounds into MP3 and save it into `~/Downloads/sounds`.

```bsh
mkdir ~/Downloads/sounds; for i in /path/to/sounds/*.{oga,ogg}; do ffmpeg -i "$i" ~/Downloads/sounds/"${i%.*}.mp3"; done
```